# How to get HTML from the URL and display it in certain place?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm in progress with my first application in visual basic, and I'm using the visual basic studio - My question is, how can I get raw HTML data from specified URL, and then display it in my form on the certain position?

I havent tried anything yet, because I havent found much solutions about this on the internet.

Comment: Yes, forms are created using the VB Studio.

Comment: You may want to be just a touch less ambitious with your first VB project. It sounds like you want to pull certain data out of a site and display it in a form, not just display the page itself. That means pulling the data down, parsing it for specific things... that is a fair amount of work I can tell you that. I did it years ago and it was quite a bit of work to get the specific data.

Comment: O_o, uh, not really the data is already prepared by the PHP script... All I need to do in vb.net is to fetch the URL content and display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `HttpClient` class or the `WebClient` class to get the raw HTML as a string.  Then, you can simply display the string in any control on your form such as a `TextBox` or `Label` control.

For instance:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Label1.Text = client.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any examples on how to implement those to the form code?

Comment: Thank you :-). Do you know, if its possible to display HTML content inside of the label? Are there any external classes for that?

Comment: No. A label can only display plain text. If you want to render HTML, you need a tool such as the web browser control that is capable of performing that very complex task. There may be tools that allow you to render to an image, PDF or document file of some sort, then you could display the output in a PictureBox.