# Awesomium - How to get HTML code of a web page?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, awesomium

This is my best attempt, but it doesn't seem to retrieve the body of html (i get only the head part).

```
Dim page_source As String = DirectCast((From k In DirectCast(Reflection.Type _
            Info.GetTypeFromHandle(WebControl2.GetType.TypeHandle),  _
            Reflection.TypeInfo).DeclaredMembers Where k.Name = "qnTkKOiivD"). _
            First, FieldInfo).GetValue(WebControl1)
```

"qnTkKOiivD" is the name of the private property that holds what seems to be the pagesource in the Awesomium WebControl.

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499908/how-to-get-html-from-the-url-and-display-it-in-certain-place

Comment: Would not work for me as I need to check the current source of the page (the loaded dom, with javascript modifications enacted, or with javascript disabled) while displaying it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even an easier way than using javascript. There should be a property called `HTML` on your WebView that yields the html.

**EDIT:**

There apparently has been a bug causing the property to only return the `<head>` tag. This bug is resolved in the latest updated version (1.7.5.0).

Comment: To me, it only yelds the <head> tag.

Comment: That is strange. Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net), for IWebView.HTML it states 'Gets the HTML code of the currently loaded document.' (Unfortunately there is no direct link)

Comment: I made some tests, for me (1.7.5.0) it yields the <html> tag, but it does not the complete DOM... You only get the <head> tag, I do only get a part of the DOM... so I suppose there is something strange. I'm quite sure it used to work in older versions.

Comment: However, the most important thing is that I don't get <body> with it.

Comment: I get the <body> tag. Can you post a minimal example as a seperate question on [Awesomium Answers](http://answers.awesomium.com). I will also create a minmal example. So if we have two examples yielding different results, the Awesomium Team has something to work with.

Comment: I'm working on it :) however I have also read that the HTML property only works if JS is enabled, so I think it uses `document.body.innerHTML` under the hood.

Comment: it was a bug and it has been corrected in some 1.7.5 update. Meanwhile I switched to windows 8.x, re-downloaded the setup file from awesomium website, and the problem vanished.

Comment: The newest version is still 1.7.5.0 as I see on their website. Does this update not increase the version number?

Comment: The `WebControl.ProductVersion` property is still that. Maybe it was some little fix... I don't know but it works, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get HTML code from Awesomium `WebControl` pretty easy and even without reflection by using its [ExecuteJavascriptWithResult](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_ExecuteJavascriptWithResult.htm) method.

Something like this:

```
_WebControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.body.innerHTML");
```

Note you should handle [DocumentReady](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_DocumentReady.htm) event to be ensured your document loading is complete.